# Drop view which does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am unable to create a view. It throws an error that that table already exists, but if I try to drop it, it says unknown table. I checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538908/schrodingers-mysql-table-exists-yet-it-does-not) but it didnt help much.

```
drop view if exists foo;
create view foo ... ;
# Table foo already exists
drop table / DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
# unknown table foo
```

`Flush table/repair table` didnt solve either. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is there a view of that name?  `DROP VIEW foo` ?

Comment: DROP VIEW foo; That's it.

Comment: Sorry, missed out adding that.

Comment: Title is misleading, Drop table is not equal to Drop View....

Comment: @Bondye I am trying to create a view, but it throws error for table already exists with same name, but dropping it throws unknown table name error.

Comment: `DROP VIEW foo;` and `CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM bar;`

Answer (score 35):

use the following syntax to replace the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `my_view` AS SELECT ...
```

Comment: nice! I thought this was a oracle thing, but then I tried. Sweet