# How can I reset a 'ghost' table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My computer was recently wiped and restored, and one of the tables in my `MySQL` database has entered a ghost-like state: I cannot delete it, I get an error claiming the table doesn't exist, and I cannot create a new table with that name, I get an error claiming the table already exists. This table did not have any important information in it, so I think the easiest thing would be to delete it for good. Any way I can do this? I'm running the database locally, so I have access to everything.

Here are the exact errors:

When I try to drop the table:

```
#1051 - Unknown table 'sessions'
```

When I try to create a new table:

```
#1050 - Table '`database`.`sessions`' already exists
```

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538908/schrodingers-mysql-table-exists-yet-it-does-not?rq=1) has some potentially helpful suggestions.

Comment: can you drop the entire schema from where that table is from?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Unfortunately, the answers there don't seem to be helping me. I'll keep trying these.

Comment: @CIRCLE I'd rather not. There's a lot of other stuff that could be troublesome to recreate. I might have to try this as a last resort.

Comment: @Strawberry It is not a view.

Comment: Sounds like something exists on the filesystem that shouldn't..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yeah, but the question is where?

Comment: @CIRCLE I deleted the database and re-imported another copy, that worked.

Comment: So you tried `DROP VIEW sessions;` ?

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, and was told that the view did not exist.