# MySQL Tables "do not exist" even though they are there

Tags: mysql

So I uninstalled my Zend web server, backed up my databases from 'MySQL55/data' and removed all folders associated with zend/apache/mysql. I then reinstalled Zend and MySQL and deployed the phpMyAdmin app for Zend. Then copied and pasted my databases back into the 'MySQL55/data' folder and opened up phpMyAdmin and clicked on a database then a table, to which it told me the table does not exist.

I also tried to access the tables from the command prompt.

[image: MySQL Command Prompt]

Clearly the tables are there but when I try to select data from them I get this error.

I've had a good read through problems other people have had but none seem to be the same as this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Dave.

Comment: Are you sure the character encoding of the table names is the same as the character encoding in your shell window?

Comment: you may need to flush the tables?

Comment: Have you checked this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist

Comment: Didn't see that question but sounds like my problem! Now my only problem is that I don't have these other files :(

Comment: All sorted, found those files for the InnoDB tables, you sir are a gentleman. Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 2):

Top voted answer on this question was my solution. Many thanks to Akarsh for finding it!

[MySQL Table does not exist error, but it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist)