# MySQL - Cannot query existing tables

Tags: mysql, sql, lowercase

I have a MySQL database (running on Ubunutu) with whole bunch of tables with names in camelcase. For example, when I call `show tables;` I get an output like

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_[schema]                |
+-----------------------------------+
| tabHelloWorld                     |
| tabUserAccounts                   |
| tabHistory                        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

However, when I'm trying to query a table, e.g., `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabHistory`, I get the error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'schema.tabhistory' doesn't exist
```

Note the table name in all lowercase. The query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabhistory` returns the same error.

I assume it has something to with the variable `lower_case_table_names`. It's currently set to 1, where I assumed that MySQL is not considering the case of table names. If I set `lower_case_table_names = 0` the query with `FROM tabHistory` is working. The problem is that the MySQL server is running other databases in turn are no longer accessible if I make that change.

How can I access my tables now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist

Comment: If you use `lower_case_table_names = 1` then you shouldn't put uppercase letters in table names. You need to rename those tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you changed the setting of `lower_case_table_names` after creating these tables. This isn't a supported configuration. When `lower_case_table_names=1`, the system automatically converts the table names to lowercase when they're created, but it doesn't go back and fix up previously existing tables. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) says:

> If you plan to set the `lower_case_table_names` system variable to `1` on Unix, you must first convert your old database and table names to lowercase before stopping `mysqld` and restarting it with the new variable setting. To do this for an individual table, use `RENAME TABLE`:
>
> ```
> RENAME TABLE T1 TO t1;
> ```

What I think you need to do now is set it back to `0` temporarily, rename these tables, then restart `mysqld`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with the quotes on table name? I'm not particularly sure but using quotes might help as it surely does in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'tabHistory';
```

Comment: MySQL uses backticks to quote table and column names.

Comment: why not try with backticks then according to @barmar?

Comment: Oh, I used both ways, of course. Sorry for not being immediately clear.